# Showing MFC tear off menus vertically

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I realize that this is a bit old: nowadays most MS stuff is ribbon based but I decided to play with tear-off menus just for the fun of it.  Tear Off menus first appeared in VS2008.  The one and only example program is supposed to be in Wordpad but that piece of sample code is no longer available.  Only the VS2003 and VS2005 versions are available but that was before the tear-off menus.  Other than the Code Project version, which is completely different, I can't find any sample code.  The MSDN help just tells you what each routine does but there is nothing on the website to tell you how to create tear off menus in MFC.

After about 3 hours of messing about, I managed to get the CMenuTearOffManager in MFC working and I could see tear off menus.  I can add how to do this to the SO documentation if anyone is interested.  I can add a SVE but it will have a lot of the autogenerated MFC code which totals up to a few hundred lines.  I could zip it up but I don't know how to add zip files to SO.

This is what the tear off menu looks like.  Click on the dotted line and drag down to tear off.

[image: Tear off menu]

This is what it looks like when it is torn off

[image: Torn off menu]

This is what it looks like when it is stretched vertically

[image: Stretched Vertically]

Short of rewriting the manager and possibly the whole of the MFC menu system, is there a simple way of

- Showing the tear offs as words and icons.  Unlike the Solaris/Motif versions, the MFC version only shows icons if there is an icon for the menu item.  It doesn't show the words as well.
- Getting the menu to show vertically instead of horizontally?  At the moment, I need to drag the popup box vertically.  By default, it pops up in horizontal format.

Comment: The menu bars are shown as words only. Sub menus can have icon+text, but only in drop-down mode. The menu bar can be docked vertically. There are several MFC examples which have left/right docking, you can drag & drop the menu bar in to them, the menu bar will show the text with vertical alignment. I reckon you need owner-draw for showing icon+text for menu bar.

Comment: These aren't docking menu bars - they are tear off menus.

Comment: I've added some pictures - finally figured out how to add pictures.